# Excel rounding down to a specific number

Tags: excel, rounding, formula

I need a help with Excel. Can't figure out the formula for a number to round down to 10010. 
There is a column which calculates numbers and I want when the result is over 10010, to round it down and display it. Else to show 0.

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want the entry in that column to be zero or 10010? Do you want it to display that value but retain the real value?  Do you want the display in another cell?

Comment: use a function to use the `=max(10010, A1)`

Comment: @Phil That won't work. That won't round down. Additionally, it won't return 0 if `A1` is less than 10010.

Comment: fair enough - should have added the ? that I meant to include the comment, as I wasn't sure if excel actually did this! Now I know.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean with rounding down? Is 10010 integer or binary? Etc. Please give a minimal complete verifiable example

Answer (score 2):

if you would like to change the number (cell `A1`) to `10010` if it is greater than or equal to `10010`, and if it is blank or less than `10010` set it to `0` this formula would work for you.

```
=IF(A1>=10010,10010,0)
```

---

In response to your comment if in cell B1 you put the formula:

```
 =MIN(IF(A1:A20>10010,A1:A20))
```

...and make sure you press CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER instead of just ENTER when coming out of formula. This will turn it into an array formula and will return you next largest value to 10010 from you range A1:A20.

In cell C1 can then just put:

```
 =B1-10010
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It is a continuing calculation. Let's put it that way:
from A1 to A20 there is a calculation with progressive numbers (10, 50, 1000, 2000, 5012, 7813, 9582, 12059, 53812... etc.)
When it hits a number , larger than 10010, B1 to round down to 10010 and in C1 to show the difference between both numbers. In this case 12059 - 10010.

Comment: @Ktown I will mod answer.